# Compiling source code that uses Boost, wxWidgets and Python with MingW

Tags: python, c++, boost, g++

I have been trying to compile a source code but every time I use the make command, it gives me the error:

```
In file included from ../src/MadEditFrame.cpp:60:0:
../src/EmbeddedPython.hpp:11:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
```

I had been able to pass the Boost and wxWidget part. This Python part is what makes no sense. I have Python 3.8 installed, it is recognised by system when in command line i use the Python --version command as 3.8.2 g++ too is recognised as 6.3.0 with Mingw.

Update:

The code has three makefiles with terminations: install, mac and mingw. I'm using the one with mingw by copying and deleting termination. The content of said file is too long, but there is a part that goes this:

```
...
      ./Release/nsUTF8Prober.obj \
       $(RES)

LINKOBJ = $(OBJ)

#WXWIN = D:\wxWidgets28_SVN
WXWIN = C:\wxWidgets-3.1.5
#XPRESSIVE_DIR = N:/boost
XPRESSIVE_DIR = ../xpressive
#BOOST_DIR = D:/boost
BOOST_DIR = C:\Programs\boost_1_77_0\boost

LIBS =  -L$(WXWIN)/lib/gcc_lib -L"../libunicows" -mwindows -lwxmsw28u_core -lwxbase28u -lunicows -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lrpcrt4 -ladvapi32 -lwsock32 -lodbc32 -lopengl32 -lgmon -s
#-g -pg
CXXINCS =  -I$(XPRESSIVE_DIR) -I$(BOOST_DIR) -I"../charset-detector/include" -I"../charset-detector/src" -I"../charset-detector/src/tables" -I$(WXWIN)/include  -I$(WXWIN)/lib/gcc_lib/mswu

BIN  = Release/MadEdit.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) -D_UNICODE -D__WXMSW__ -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WIN95__ -DWIN32 -O2
#-g -pg
RM = rm -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before Release/MadEdit.exe all-after
...
```

I added the paths under the commented ones for **WXWIN** and **BOOSTDIR**

Comment: Linking error probably. It is not able to find Python.h file, check your include paths.

Comment: The include path in System or from some part in the code or option while invoking make command?
In either case, how should be done that?

Comment: Are you using Makefiles? Then you need to include the path containing Python headers using `-I` option and link to the path containing Python library files using `-L` option.

Comment: Indeed it has a Makefile. It has three in fact, but it seems depends on which compiler is used. So i'm using one which has this part: LIBS =  -L$(WXWIN)/lib/gcc_lib -L"../libunicows" -mwindows -lwxmsw28u_core -lwxbase28u -lunicows -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lrpcrt4 -ladvapi32 -lwsock32 -lodbc32 -lopengl32 -lgmon -s
#-g -pg
CXXINCS =  -I$(XPRESSIVE_DIR) -I$(BOOST_DIR) -I"../charset-detector/include" -I"../charset-detector/src" -I"../charset-detector/src/tables" -I$(WXWIN)/include  -I$(WXWIN)/lib/gcc_lib/mswu

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, it's difficult to read. Please update the post and add this there.

Comment: Is `EmbeddedPython.hpp` located in some dependency? What is this source code that you are trying to compile - is it open source?

Comment: The EmbeddedPython.hpp is located inside a folder in root called src. The code is from a github repository which is also a modified version of another github open source code. A little problem is that the installation instructions are terribly done and has not been updated in literally years (i checked the original one and has the same in "how to install"). This is from MadEdit-Mod in a github repository.